# Geany compilation error

Tags: html, geany, css

What is this error about:
/bin/sh 1: tidy: not found

when I compile the HTML file this error shows up in the compiler window. Html file works, but I'm afraid that this may create problem, so please guide me about this.

Comment: How do you "compile" an HTML file? Also, have you just tried installing [`tidy`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/tidy)?

Comment: I clicked the compile button in toolbar, and at the bottom of editor screen in compiler view section it appears. "Installed tidy?", Actually I knew nothing about this i.e. if its a plugin or separate app.

Comment: Thank you @muru, You've just guided me into right direction and I've just installed the Tidy using following command: I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.

$ sudo apt  install tidy